# Why were square brackets used to contain these words?

Tags: punctuation, square-brackets

It is easy for guys
like [Stuart] Broad and [Ben] Stokes who have been
doing it for years. I don't think Shafiul [Islam] and Kamrul
[Islam Rabbi] bowled that badly. (Collected from a national daily)

Consider those sentences and tell me why the writer has used square bracket in the name of those player?  And Why not always first part of a name or second part? why sometimes first and sometimes second part?

Comment: Because ordinarily the author would just refer to them as *Broad and Stokes* but he realizes that not all his readers will know who he's talking about so he's added more details in square brackets.  As in, "Broad (and by Broad I mean Stuart Broad)" etc.  At the same time he wishes people to know that they *should* recognize them by the single name and therefore doesn't simply write the full name without brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a quotation? Square brackets are used to indicate words that have been inserted into some text by the writer to provide clarification. It is traditional to identify cricketers by their last names, and I suspect that the original text might have been:

> It is easy for guys like Broad and Stokes who have been doing it for
>   years. I don't think Shafiul and Kamrul bowled that badly.

Finally, the writer tells us (with a parenthetical comment) that the text was from a national daily newspaper.

Comment: Right on point, I'd say.  And then we have "...[sic]..." which should always be wrapped up nicely in square brackets in a quote, what?

Comment: Indubitable, innit?

Comment: Ahhhhh! The 'innit-bin-it' man is back!

Comment: "Innit [sic & thrice sick]" is indisputably the day's shibboleth-of-choice, what?

Comment: Stop it at once! You're making me spill my rum. That's another keyboard I've got to clean.